# SQL Counting the amount of times a value from one table shows up in another

Tags: sql

I am trying to work out how to go about this one SQL query.

I have two tables `Orders` and `Customers`.

`Orders` has two columns `CustomerNumber` and `Fruit`

`Customers` has two columns as well `CustomerNumber` and `Address`

Not all customers have placed an order but I need a query that runs through the list of `Customers.CustomerNumber` and lists how many times that `Customers.CustomerNumber` times shows up in the table `Orders`.

It's a countif query but im not sure how to set it up.

Comment: Your Orders table will need some reference to the Customers table. Orders should have columns: ID, Fruit, and CustomerID.

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer.id, count(order.*)
from Customer inner join Order on Customer.id=Order.ID
group by customer.id
```

Comment: hmm it doesn't show the ones with 0 in them. 

Can I include them somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.CustomerNumber, count(1)
from Customer as c
left join Order as o on c.CustomerNumber = o.CustomerNumber 
group by c.CustomerNumber
```

This will return a zero for customer's without any orders.

Comment: i fixed my original question, how aobut now.